# Readonly public property redeclared as readwrite in private interface.. understanding a bit more

Tags: objective-c, properties, redeclaration

I've read the *Property redeclaration* chapter in [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) document and I'd like if some of you can clarify me the following property redeclaration:

```
// MyObject.h public header file

@interface MyObject : NSObject {
    NSString *language;
}
@property (readonly, copy) NSString *language;
@end


// MyObject.m private implementation file
@interface MyObject ()
@property (readwrite, copy) NSString *language;
@end

@implementation MyObject
@synthesize language;
@end
```

I just want to understand if the above `@property` and `@synthesize` keywords produce the following code:

```
// MyObject.h public header file

@interface MyObject : NSObject {
    NSString *language;
}
-(NSString *)language;
@end


// MyObject.m private implementation file
@interface MyObject ()
-(void)setLanguage: (NSString *) aString;
@end

@implementation MyObject
-(NSString *)language {
    return language;
}

-(void)setLanguage: (NSString *) aString {
    [language release];
    language = [aString copy];
}
@end
```

So, what happens is that the compiler sees the first `@property` declaration and adds a getter method in the public interface... than, when it comes to the implementation file it finds another `@property` declaration for the same property but with readwrite attribute within the private interface and adds only a setter method since the getter has been already added to the public interface.. then, the `@synthesize` keyword is found and both implementations are added to the private implementation section.. the copy attribute of the first `@property` declaration would not be necessary, since the setter is not needed there, but we must specify it to be consistent with the second property redeclaration. Are my thoughts right?

Comment: Almost, but as you do not specify `nonatomic` the setter and getter code is synchronised to be thread safe.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was just not thinking about that important thing, because I was focused on the redeclaration doubts and not strictly on the way the `@synthesize` implements the getter and setter methods. BTW, thank you for pointing it out ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct.

Also note that there are no strictly private methods in Objective-C. An external caller can still call `setLanguage:`. The compiler will output a warning but the message would get through at runtime.

Comment: Ok, it is simply not exposed in the public interface and so you (the developer that uses the class) should not invoke the setter method, but the runtime is still able to deliver the message since the corresponding method has been effectively implemented for the class.. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: One area that the ability to call private methods is very useful is in Unit Testing.