# Having readonly nsarray property and nsmutable array not readonly with the same name and _ in xcode 4.2 vs 4.5

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am following a tutorial from Ray Wenderlich site and i am trying to understand this code where it has nsarray readonly and nsmutableble array with the same name but writable.  Also what is the reason to use _(underscore)property vs setting a property and using self.x  Here is the code:
this is from the site

MatchmakingServer.h

```
@interface MatchmakingServer : NSObject <GKSessionDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) int maxClients;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSArray *connectedClients;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) GKSession *session;

- (void)startAcceptingConnectionsForSessionID:(NSString *)sessionID;

@end
```

MatchmakingServer.m

```
#import "MatchmakingServer.h"

@implementation MatchmakingServer
{
    NSMutableArray *_connectedClients;
}

@synthesize maxClients = _maxClients;
@synthesize session = _session;

- (void)startAcceptingConnectionsForSessionID:(NSString *)sessionID
{
    _connectedClients = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.maxClients];

    _session = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:sessionID displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModeServer];
    _session.delegate = self;
    _session.available = YES;
}
```

I am doing something like this instead

matchmakingserver.h

```
@interface zvMatchMakingServer : NSObject <GKSessionDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) int maxClients;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSArray *connectedClients;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) GKSession *session;

- (void)startAcceptingConnectionsForSessionID:(NSString *)sessionID;


@end
```

matchmakingserver.m

```
@interface zvMatchMakingServer()

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *connectedClients;
@property (nonatomic, strong) GKSession *session;

@end

@implementation zvMatchMakingServer


-(NSArray *)connectedClients
{
    return self.connectedClients;
}

-(void)startAcceptingConnectionsForSessionID:(NSString *)sessionID
{
    self.connectedClients = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:self.maxClients];
    self.session = [[GKSession alloc]initWithSessionID:sessionID displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModeServer];

}
```

Is what i am doing basically the same thing or it won't work.  Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Readonly public property redeclared as readwrite in private interface.. understanding a bit more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566384/readonly-public-property-redeclared-as-readwrite-in-private-interface-understa)

Comment: I saw this question before but i am working with iOS 6 and i guess 5 the declaration is a little different so i am not sure how it works now with redeclaration.  Also I am not sure if i had to use copy in my declaration of the property.

Comment: The only difference is that with the newest Apple LLVM compiler (note this has nothing to do with the iOS version), you don't have to include the `@synthesize` directive. The functionality has not changed.

Comment: So then what i am doing should work and is considered rediclaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to explain what happens in Ray's code:

He declares a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSArray *connectedClients;
```

(I assume this was pre iOS 6, because in iOS 6 Apple changed the way properties generate iVars.)

This property causes the compiler to automatically generate an iVar `NSArray *connectedClients`. This iVar is not used in the code. Instead he's declaring a new (private) iVar named `_connectedClients` of type `NSMutableArray`. Note that he doesn't synthesize the accessors for the property. He writes the accessor himself and instead of returning the iVar generated by the property (connectedClients), he's returning his 'own' iVar (_connectedClients):

```
- (NSArray *)connectedClients
{
    return _connectedClients;
}
```

Since `NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray` there's no problem doing that.

What you're doing is trying to redeclare the property `@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *connectedClients;` as private property and that's not allowed. Carefully compare your code to Ray's, then you'll see the difference.

As for the underscore:

That's only a convention many people use to name their iVars. It has no semantical meaning. 
In fact Apple changed the names of 'auto-generated' iVars to also use the underscore.

Pre iOS 6 a property

```
@property (...) SomeClass *name;
```

generated an iVar named `name`. In iOS 6 that same property generates an iVar named `_name`. Also in iOS 6 you don't need to add the `@synthesize` line anymore.

Prefixing names of iVars with an underscore was convenient because if you wanted to override an automatically generated accessor the autocompletion suggested this:

```
- (void)setName:(SomeClass *)name
```

if your iVar was also named `name` the parameter `name` would hide the iVar in the accessor implementation, so you had to change the name of the parameter. If you renamed your iVar by using `@synthesize name = _name` the parameter `name` did no longer hide it and you could use the autocompletion generated code for the accessor.

```
- (void)setName:(SomeClass *)name
{
    //maybe release the old value and retain the new one if you're not using ARC and weather it's a retained property or not. 
   _name = name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and your explanation! So as i understand  NSMutableArray *_connectedClients; means that he is declaring a totally new variable called _connectedClients which is not tied in with connectedClients and then he returns it in the getter of connectedClients.  _connectedClients could be named anything name ex. prvConnectedClients.  The underscore confused me a little.  I thought they variables connected in some way.

Comment: That is correct. (**If** (and I'm not 100% sure about this) it's a pre iOS 6 'version', i.e. the synthesized iVar is named `connectedClients`, in iOS 6 the synthesized iVar would also be named `_connectedClients`, in which case the declaration in the `@implementation` part would override the auto-synthesized iVar. But the effect would be the same)

Comment: Auto-synthesize has nothing to do with iOS version; it is a compiler feature. No ivar is created without a `@synthesize`, automatic or explicit. An `@property` directive only declares _methods_, not storage (i.e., an ivar).

Comment: The code works the way it is now.  What about the whole redeclaration of properties.  Does this apply here or it is something different?  Thanks again!

Comment: @JoshCaswell You're right, I was not precise. The changes I was referring to (renaming auto-synthesized iVar and remove the need to explicitly call `@synthesize`) were applied to the LLVM compiler by the time Apple annouced iOS 6. But of course you're right, it has nothing to do with iOS, my bad :)